# Writing string to cell

Tags: string, excel, vba

This should be very straightforward but for some reason I'm having issues. The code should look at a particular cell, if it meets the criteria of the IF statement, write the data to another cell.

```
dim i as integer
i = 1

For i = 1 To 674
    If Sheets("Provider Data").Cells(i + 3, 60).Value2 = 8 Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2 + i, 1).Value2 = Sheets("Provider Data").Cells(i + 3, 3).Value2
    End If
Next i
```

For some reason the data wont write to the cell. I've debugged with message boxes, and the If statement correctly selects the cells that match 8, but for some reason the contents of

```
sheets("Provider Data").cells(i+3,3).value2
```

aren't written to the cell. What am I missing? I should mention the data to be written to the cell from (i+3,3) are strings

Comment: Have you tried dropping the '.Value2' from all the code?

Comment: I have, no change. Initially I used .value but I still have the same issue.

Comment: please try using Range(i+3,3)

Comment: Specifically which range on "Provider data" contains the text to write and are there any merged cells? Generally, it's easier to use column *letters* rather than numbers with the `Cells` command unless you are calculating the column number.

Comment: Range(i + 3, 3).Value gives object-defined error. As far as I know range() must contain quoted cell references no?

Comment: Your code looks fine -- I think that you are just copying the contents of blank cells and have something wrong with your `Cells` expressions. For debugging purposes, try using `.Address` instead of `.Value2` at the end of `Sheets("Provider Data").Cells(i + 3, 3).Value2` and see the addresses of the cells that you are trying to copy.

Comment: debugging with .Address shows that it is pointed in the right location. I tried 
    
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value to test and it was able to write a single value to A1

how can I use variable names so that it moves down the rows? Something like Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).value ???

Comment: Also tried .cells(1,1) to test and that also works. There seems to be some issue when using i to specify the cell refrence.

Comment: Just to check, your code checks BH4:BH677 on 'Provider data' and if a given cell equals 8, it writes the value from column C same row, to column A, one row up on sheet1. If that's correct, are you sure the values are exactly equal to 8? Have you debugged at all?

Comment: Hopefully you are not using `On Error Resume Next` while trying to write into protected cells.